# SearchBar not displaying results until cancel button clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, uitableview, uisearchbar

I  have implemented a UITableView with search bar (and search display) - all works fine, but the table results do not get updated until the search bar cancel button is tapped.

Delegate methods:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // asynchronous request with [self.tableView reloadData] in the connectionDidFinishLoading
    [self getProductData:searchBar.text]; 
 [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 [self.tableView reloadData];


}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar  {  
} 

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
 return YES;
}
```

Do I need to call a delegate method after receiving the data from the server?  Or should I make the request synchronous?

Thanks

---

edit:  I tried with a synchronous request and it still does not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding this code to the end of my getProductData method:

```
[[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Brilliant, used [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; and then created -(void)reloadData{[table reloadData];} and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

and return YES

See the [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code

Comment: Thanks - I've already tried that, but it still does not work. I also included - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption

Comment: Hummm, I used UISearchDisplayController, not UISearchBarDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self getProductData:searchText]; 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and this causes the HTTP request to be called every time text in the search bar changes - in my case this causes the app to crash.

Comment: In that case u should consider to change the design of ur app.