# UISearch bar not showing result until did not click on cancel button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search functionality. which will take input from user and will return result when pressed Search button.
I have search [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042111/searchbar-not-displaying-results-until-cancel-button-clicked).

But this example is not useful for me. I have a cade like that.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Setup the Location Search bar Controller
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

    searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar

    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

> Another Function is

```
extension SearchViewController : UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.view.isHidden = false
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.viewList.removeAll()
    getListOfItem(searchBar.text!)
 }
}
```

> And my `getListOfItem` taking data from data base and after receiving data i am reloading my `UITableView` from that function.

```
func getListOfItem(_ query : String){
    if !loadingData {
        self.viewList.removeAll()
    }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: MyUrl.API_SERVER_URL)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "tag=search&p=\(query)&page=\(String(pageNo))"
    print("postString=\(postString)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.startSpinner()
    }
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        if(error != nil){
            self.loadingData = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.stopSpinner()
            }
            let nsError = error! as NSError
            let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Internal Server Error?", message: nsError.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.present(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

        } else{
            self.loadingData = false
            do {
                var success : Int = 0
                let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                success = jsonObj["success"]! as! Int
                if success == 1 {
                    let json = jsonObj["data"]as? NSArray
                    self.pageNo = self.pageNo + 1
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        for i in 0 ..< json!.count {
                            let productObj  = json![i]as? [String: AnyObject]
                            let newModel = Search()
                            newModel.attributeId =  productObj!["AttributeID"] as? String
                            newModel.attributePrice = productObj!["AttributePrice"] as? String
                            newModel.imageURL = productObj!["ImageURL"] as? String
                            newModel.inventoryCurrent = productObj!["InventoryCurrent"] as? String
                            newModel.pageText = productObj!["PageText"] as? String
                            newModel.productDescription = productObj!["ProductDescription"] as? String
                            newModel.pageURL = productObj!["PageURL"] as? String
                            newModel.productID = productObj!["ProductID"] as? String
                            newModel.productName = productObj!["ProductName"] as? String
                            newModel.thumbURL = productObj!["ThumbURL"] as? String
                            newModel.internationalShipping = productObj!["internationalShipping"] as? String
                            newModel.maxQty = productObj!["maxQty"] as? String
                            newModel.productDisplay = productObj!["productDisplay"] as? String
                            self.viewList.append(newModel)

                        }

                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("reload")
                    self.checkItems()
                    self.viewListTable.reloadData()
                    //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            } catch {
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.stopSpinner()
            })
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

> This function is getting data from data base and also reloading `myTableView`. Result is not showing until i clicked on **`cancel`** button of `UISearchBar`.
>   Please help me for that thanks.
>
> **UPDATED**
>   I have just resolve that issue after adding some code in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked()` i have add `self.resultSearchController?.view.isHidden = true` this line but here i can not scroll my table directly. Means i can scroll my table after on tap on that

Comment: add this method getListOfItem with string argument in question.

Comment: @KKRocks i forgot add that thing in my question please check now. I have already add that to my function.

Comment: are you doing any operation in this method except reload ?

Comment: @KKRocks Just Getting Data from server and after getting that just try to reload my `UITableView`

Comment: i cant see how to data fetch data from in  getListOfItem .

Comment: @KKRocks Check my edited function for getting data from server..

Comment: add self.view.isHidden = false before tableview reload .

Comment: and is this your self.viewListTable for search ?

Comment: @KKRocks `self.view.isHidden = false` is not working and please tell me about your last comment didn't get it. I am still can see my result on clicking by `Cancel` button

Comment: self.viewListTable is that tableview which displayed your search data .

Comment: @KKRocks this is my table view which will show my result

Comment: it is not not try to check is it nil or not.

Comment: @KKRocks can please tell me why i can see my result after click on cancel button?

Comment: because you actual tableview reload on cancel button click event . can you post that ?

Comment: @KKRocks Why this not happening on `reloadData()` function of `UITableView` ?

Comment: because it is empty or not your actual tableview which used for displayed for search .

Comment: @KKRocks can i bring my resultant table view in front when result came from server

Comment: @KKRocks can you please check my updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After Adding some line of code in my `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`. My problem is getting resolved.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.viewList.removeAll()
    self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()//This Line Remove the keyboard
    self.resultSearchController?.view.isHidden = true // This line Hide current View
    self.viewListTable.reloadData()
    pageNo = 1
    self.searchStr = searchBar.text! // This Line taking a search string into global variable for future use.
    self.resultSearchController?.isActive = false // This Line for inActivate searchView.
    getListOfItem()
}
```

> Before using `Make Sure` the hierarchy of all line which is written in that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.view.isHidden = false
    getListOfItem(searchBar.text!)
}
```

> I think you missed adding this `getListOfItem(searchBar.text!)` in `func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)`

Comment: let me try and will get back you soon and one more thing i want result on `Search` button pressed. will it work for that?..

Comment: No it didn't worked and still getting result after click on cancel button

Comment: Could you share the code for TableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: I have just resolve that issue after adding some code in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked()` i have add `self.resultSearchController?.view.isHidden = true` this line but here i can not scroll my table directly. Means i can scroll my table after on tap on that

Comment: Yes, the table displaying search results will scroll only when you tap on it

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort but i have resolve that issue please check my answer.

Comment: You are welcome, please accept(by clicking the check mark) your own answer as it will tell others that you have found a solution.

Comment: Ok Thanks for telling me i did try to accept but i can accept my own answer after two days.

Comment: Ok. but please do that, it would help others.